# How to use $this.nextTick() to emit event to parent component after child component finishes rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling

I have two components, `parentComponent` and `childComponent`.

`parentComponent` passes a prop called `booleanValue` to `childComponent` whose value is used inside the `nextTick()` callback to perform some processing.

My child component is performing its method likeso:

```
mounted() {
this.$nextTick(()=>{
      if (this.booleanValue){
        alert('You got it!')
        this.$emit('event-name');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and my parent component processes it like so:

```
<child-component 
    v-on:event-name=eventMethod
    v-bind:booleanValue=this.booleanValue>
</child-component>
```

and my `eventMethod()` is described under `methods: {...}`

My code is syntactically correct but I can't get the nextTick to perform it in the way I want to. What I'm trying to achieve is that the child component would finish rendering the new DOM and then emit an event back to the parent who then does some other processing.

What am I doing wrong? I would prefer to use this solution instead of attempting to solve via other implementations like the Options API, if possible. I haven't learned that yet and I fear I'll be introducing more frustration if I try to learn it now for this one problem.

Comment: It's unknown if booleanValue is changed and how it's supposed to be handled. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, it's specific to details that were omitted. Generally it may be done like it was done. It could be a watcher with `flush: post`.

Comment: Regardless of whether booleanValue is changed or not, the problem is with my ```nextTick()``` method which isn't being invoked on DOM update of that component. I am able to confirm this by console logging before the if condition in my example and seeing nothing being printed.

Comment: It's not supposed to, you asked about the behaviour that doesn't exist. This is what watchers are for